# Can nginx log time in ISO 8601 format, but include milliseconds?

Tags: nginx, logging, timestamp

We have Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat.  Both of them log access with ISO 8601 timestamps, but tomcat adds in milliseconds (which is part of the standard).  So if Nginx gets a request and passes it onto Tomcat, the Nginx log might have a timestamp of "2015-10-29T00:37:02+00:00" and Tomcat will have a timestamp of "2015-10-29T00:37:02,106+0000" for the same access. I'm not concerned about the minor differences in formatting, but not having milliseconds (the ",106" part in the Tomcat log) is a problem because it prevents us from correlating the logs correctly.

Is there any way to make Nginx include milliseconds in it's logs?

Comment: Did you check the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)?

Comment: Yes I did.  From that I can't see any way to log ISO 8601 timestamps with millisecond resolution, but that seems like a ridiculous oversight to me, especially given that it can log msec timestamps with millisecond resolution. So I was wondering/hoping that someone might know of a way to make Nginx log the way I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, based on reading the source code to nginx, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this. You would need to post-process the logs (you could take the output of $msec and turn it into ISO8601 with ms yourself) or patch nginx to add this.

Interestingly a patch was proposed years ago that would have given enough flexibility to make it possible, but I don't think it went anywhere: 
http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-time-custom-supports-a-custom-log-timestamp-td3505292.html#none

Comment: https://thatsamguy.com/nginx-iso8601-time-format/

Answer (score 6):

The question requested ISO 8601 plus milliseconds - here is a one-liner for that specific use case, based on Oleksandr's answer but using ISO rather than local format:

```
map "$time_iso8601 # $msec" $time_iso8601_ms { "~(^[^+]+)(\+[0-9:]+) # \d+\.(\d+)$" $1.$3$2; }
```

The result is constructed from the regex match groups as follows:

- `$1` = just the date and time part of `$time_iso8601` e.g. `2021-05-21T10:26:19`
- `$2` = just the timezone part of `$time_iso8601` e.g. `+00:00`
- `$3` = just the millisecond part of [`$msec`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_msec) e.g. `123` extracted from `1621594635.123`

If the one-liner feels too opaque, see [this post](https://thatsamguy.com/nginx-iso8601-time-format/) (as commented on another answer) which uses multiple `map` statements.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workaround that I found. Add the following line to the `http {}` block:

```
map "$time_local:$msec" $time_local_ms { ~(^\S+)(\s+\S+):\d+\.(\d+)$ $1.$3$2; }
```

Then, in your `log_format` line change `[$time_local]` to `[$time_local_ms]`, or create your own log format, e.g. the one that I use for Datadog:

```
log_format  common  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local_ms] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

Example of access log:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2021:13:06:02.802 +0000] "GET /static/image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 0.000 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla" "-"
```

---

**Source**: https://grangerx.wordpress.com/2019/08/28/nginx-improve-logs-by-adding-millisecond-msec-resolution-to-time_local/